# how to start camera intent and save a non-compressed picture

Tags: android, image, android-intent, uri, saving-data

I am a very young self taught developer and I'm working on my first major project, which requires to start a camera intent once pressed, save the image that the user took and display it in a custom dialog.
I got it to work, but i stored the returned bitmap in onactivityresult so the picture is compressed and that destroys the functionality of the app.

HERE IS THE CODE THAT DOES　WORK:

start intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Recieve Intent and send data to dialog:

```
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            File file = new File(getCacheDir() + "/app"
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 /* ignored for PNG */,
                    bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

            // write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(bitmapdata);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mdialog.setPic(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Display the picture in the custom dialog:

```
public void setPic(final String mURi) {
    this.mURI = mURi;

    if (mURI != null) {
        hwPic.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(mURI);

                   hwPic.setImageDrawable(d);;
                hwPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

This works fine but since the picture is compressed any reasonably sized font in the picture is blury and illegible.

HERE IS THE CODE THAT DOES NOT WORK:

Initialize Variable:

```
private String MURID;
```

Start intent:

File file = new File(getCacheDir() + "/app"
                                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

```
                            if(!file.exists()){
                                try {
                                    file.createNewFile();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                }else{
                                   file.delete();
                                try {
                                   file.createNewFile();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                }
                            MURID=file.getAbsolutePath();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT , Uri.parse(MURID));
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

recieve intent and send to mydialog:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {// camera intent for the dialog picture
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            mdialog.setPic(MURID);

        }
    }
}
```

setpic remains the same(in the dialog):

```
public void setPic(final String mURi) {
    this.mURI = mURi;

    if (mURI != null) {
        hwPic.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(mURI);

                   hwPic.setImageDrawable(d);;
                hwPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Im not getting any response from it and logcat didnt give me any errors either, what seems to be the problem? any help would be greatly apprecieated.

BTW: i want this to work with phones without sdcards as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third-party camera apps cannot write to your `getCacheDir()`, and some may get confused if you point to an existing file. Use external storage instead:

```
package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.io.File;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File dir=
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    output=new File(dir, "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), "image/jpeg");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content) in [this book](http://commonsware.com/Android))

> BTW: i want this to work with phones without sdcards as well.

[External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: The Image saved by MediaStore.Extra_output inside a URI saves the image inside of the provided Directory as a webp format and it also shows the file in Gallery as jpg format, How can i prevent this to be shown only inside my private folder as webp only and not in gallery as jpg format?

Comment: @JayDangar: You can't. You are delegating the photo-taking work to another app. The developers of that app can do whatever they want. If you want absolute control over the photo-taking work, do it yourself, using the camera APIs directly or by libraries that wrap those APIs (e.g., Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android).